# Limiting size of prepended img. <td>size getting skewed after using jQuery to prepend img inside td

Tags: jquery, html, css, image

I have a 3x3 table that looks like this:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td id='a1'></td>
      <td id='b1'></td>
      <td id='c1'></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td id='a2'></td>
      <td id='b2'></td>
      <td id='c2'></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td id='a3'></td>
      <td id='b3'></td>
      <td id='c3'></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Javascript (specifically jQuery/coffeescript) that looks like this:

```
$(document).ready ->
  $("td").click ->
    $("<img src='download.jpg'/>").prependTo @
```

And CSS that looks like this:

```
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: solid 1px #999999;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #cccccc;
  -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #cccccc;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #cccccc;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

table th, td {
  padding: 3px;
  line-height: 13px;
  border-left: solid 1px #AAAAAA;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #AAAAAA;
}

img {
  max-width:100px;
  max-height: 100px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin:0;
}
```

When I click on a cell and the image is prepended, I would like the image to fill in the cell and not to skew the size of my table. Basically I'd like to lock the table and the 9 cells at their current size and for the image to be prepended with no visible changes to the size/borders of the table and cells.

Currently when I prepend, the table gets skewed, the image is located on the leftmost side of the cell and the prepended cell becomes larger than all the other cells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they're a fixed size, try using `width` and `height` on your `td` CSS, instead of `max-width` and `max-height`.  See this fiddle: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/QcrPX/1/).

Answer (score 0):

if all images are the same dimensions, you could have a transparent image of that size in all the cells (100x100?), and when someone clicks, you can replace the contents of the td with the download image